# Как отключить Ajax.Autocompleter?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Уже пару тройку часов кряду не могу отключить Ajax.Autocompleter. Перерыл кучу инфы, но сделать не смог, подскажите, кто знает. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Было бы прекрасно, если бы вы дали ссылку на библиотеку в несжатом виде.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, у вас там input поле и вы хотите, чтобы не использовался автокомплит?
Советую в яваскрипте поискать *new Ajax.Autocompleter* и закомментировать.

Comment: Нет не в этом вопрос состоял, он включен и это нормально, но мне надо сделать функцию которая умеет его отключать